# Registering Receivers dynamically

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, event-receiver

I have registered receiver dynamically with service. Will receiver work after service will die?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I have a question: will receiver work after service will die?

No. It will work briefly. Eventually, Android will terminate your process, if it thinks there are no services running (or they have been running too long) and that there are no activities in the foreground.

It is bad form for a service (or an activity) to leak a receiver.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that bad form, but SCREEN_ON/OFF doesn't work from manifest, so I'm forced to use the service for the registration of the receiver.

Comment: @XXX: `SCREEN_OFF` and `SCREEN_ON` are not designed to be used except by running activities. You should consider some other solution to whatever problem you are trying to solve, as users will really dislike it if you tie up a bunch of RAM just so you can find out when the screen turns on and off.